# add AVATAR url promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I want to create todo app which foreach item I add random image from npm liberty ("@dudadev/random-img") that return promise.
It work only after the first time, It mean that the first item I create will be without image, and after it will work and create image (attach screenshot with example)[image: screenshot]

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // load items while initializing
    items: [],
    id: uuidv4(),
    item: "",
    image: "image here",
    editItem: false
  };
  
  componentDidMount(){
    const localStorageList = window.localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];
    if (!localStorageList){
      return null;
    } 
    else {
      this.setState({items: localStorageList})
    }
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    ...
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    imgGen().then(avatarURL => this.setState({ image:avatarURL }))
    const newItem = {
      id: this.state.id,
      title: this.state.item,
      image: this.state.image
    };
    const updatedItems = [...this.state.items, newItem];
    // Save items while changing
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(updatedItems));

    this.setState({
      items: updatedItems,
      item: "",
      image: "image here",
      id: uuidv4(),
      editItem: false,
    });
    
  };

  clearList = () => {
    ...

  };
  handleDelete = id => {
    ...

  };
  handleEdit = id => {
    ...
  };

  render() {
    return (
            <TodoInput
              item={this.state.item}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              editItem={this.state.editItem}
            />
            <TodoList
              items={this.state.items}
              clearList={this.clearList}
              handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
              handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
            />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The promise is async so it hasn't updated the component state by the time you add the new item to the list; in other words, `this.state.image` is still `"image here"` when you use/set `updatedItems`. Each subsequent item is actually using the image returned by the previous submit because of this.

You should move more of your code inside your `.then` so that it only adds the item when you have an image returned.

Comment: if I insert all the rest of the function code inside .then nothing works

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't. You'll need to update your code so your image isn't coming from state; it doesn't need to anymore.